# Salesforce Commerce Cloud & Figma

Tags: ui, commerce-cloud, design

I'm Oliver, a UI/UX designer within the ecommerce industry. I'm new to Salesforce Commerce Cloud and not sure which design toolkit is the right one for our relatively large scale B2c shop relaunch.

Within our current shop system we use Figma as a design system and based on this also prototyping. I'm curious to hear from your experiences: does leveraging Figma align well with Salesforce Commerce Cloud, or should the role of a UI/UX designer within this framework entail a different approach?

Thank you all for your insights and shared experiences!

Best regards,
Oliver